# What is the best way to unrar file?

Tags: java, winrar

I want to unrar a file which contains one level of files.

That's what I made so far:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Program Files\\WinRAR\\WinRAR.exe unrar -x " + inputZipFile + " " + outputFolderPath);
```

And it doesn't make anything.

Comment: Runtime.exec was replaced years ago by [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html).  Be sure to call the ProcessBuilder's [inheritIO](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO--) method so you'll see the unrar command's output.

Comment: could you give me please an example ?

Comment: Try `new ProcessBuilder("C:\\Program Files\\WinRAR\\WinRAR.exe", "unrar", "-x", inputZipFile, outputFolderPath).inheritIO().start();`.

Comment: it's not working either

Comment: What does "not working" mean?  Is your computer catching fire?  If an exception is occurring, please edit your question and add the exception's entire stack trace.  And you should show the try/catch blocks surrounding your process launching code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might give a try this library:

https://github.com/edmund-wagner/junrar

This is some example code from the author:

https://github.com/edmund-wagner/junrar/blob/master/testutil/src/main/java/com/github/junrar/testutil/ExtractArchive.java

Comment: is there anything which is not involved with git?  or either give me a link for a jar not for git please.

Comment: Seems to be this: 
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.junrar/junrar/0.7
Just click on the download  (JAR) button